# ¿Cómo inicializar el valor de primarykey en 100 con sequence en Google App Engine (GAE)?

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine

**clase consulta**

```
package model;
import javax.annotation.PropertyKey;
import javax.jdo.annotations.*;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Consulta {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE)
    private Long idusuario;

    @Persistent
    private String nombre;

    public Consulta(String nombre) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Long getIdusuario() {
        return idusuario;
    }

    public void setIdusuario(Long idusuario) {
        this.idusuario = idusuario;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Consulta [idusuario=" + idusuario + ", nombre=" + nombre +"]<br>";
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]